# Bind button from user control to viewmodel doesn't work as expected

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I Have MainWindow.xaml and MainWindowViewModel, I have User Conterol inside MainWindow.xaml, I want when user clicks User control button to send this event to MainWindowViewModel, I have:

Inside main window I have:

```
 <Controls:UserControl1 CloseBtn="{Binding CloseBtn}" ></Controls:UserControl1>
```

**UserControl1.xaml:**

```
  <Button  Command="{Binding CloseBtn}" />
```

**UserControl1.cs:**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CloseBtn",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(UserControl1),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
public ICommand CloseBtn
{
   get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CloseProperty); }
   set { SetValue(CloseProperty, value); }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs:**

```
public ICommand CloseBtn { get; set; }
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
 CloseBtn = new RelayCommand(o => BtnCloseSettings());
}
void BtnCloseSettings()
{
   MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

The MainWindow and the viewmodel are connected, but this button click doesn't popup the "test" messageBox.

what am I missing?

Comment: `Command="{Binding CloseBtn, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`. Besides that, the identifier field of a dependency property named X should be named XProperty, i.e. `CloseBtnProperty` here

Comment: @Clemens That still doesn't work :(

Comment: Then please explain what "*the MainWindow and the viewmodel are connected*" means exactly, and also make sure your UserControl does not set its own DataContext.

Comment: I mean that the DataContext of MainWindow is MainWIndowViewModel, the UserControl doesn't have it's own DataContext

Comment: Please, provide us your implementation of RelayCommand. Probably, the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line here:

```
<Button  Command="{Binding CloseBtn}" />
```

You've create a dependency property in UserControl1, which you are correctly binding with this line:

```
<Controls:UserControl1 CloseBtn="{Binding CloseBtn}" ></Controls:UserControl1>
```

But that first binding is binding to the CloseBtn property of the UserControl's DataContext. It needs to bind to the UserControl's CloseBtn dependency property instead. To fix this, start by giving your UserControl a name:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourApp.UserControl1"
    ... etc ...
    x:Name="_this">
```

And then change your button command binding to bind to that instead:

```
<Button Command="{Binding CloseBtn, ElementName=_this}" />
```

---

Or, as mentioned in a comment:

```
<Button Command="{Binding CloseBtn,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

where you wouldn't need to assign the UserControl's `x:Name` property, and thus avoid the creation of an otherwise unused private field.